# Grouping Nested Lists into Tuples

Tags: python

I am trying to group nested lists in python (I already sorted the data).  The final output should be comma separated tuples, one per line

Current nested list:

```
[['A123', '2012-01-01', 'estrogen'],
 ['A123', '2012-01-01', 'ibuprofen '],
 ['A123', '2014-01-01', 'oxaliplatin'],
 ['A123', '2014-01-01', 'penicilin']]
```

Desired outcome (comma separated tuple)

```
[(('A123', '2012-01-01', 'estrogen'),
  ('A123', '2012-01-01', 'ibuprofen ')),
 (('A123', '2014-01-01', 'oxaliplatin'),
  ('A123', '2014-01-01', 'penicilin'))]
```

I understand the sorting but don't quite know how to group the lists together into one.  The final step I assume is the convert into tuples.

Comment: There is no such thing as a comma-separated tuple. Whether it is one per line or not, depends on how you print it. Please clarify if you want to construct a list of tuples, a tuple of tuples, or something else. in particular, it is not clear why the first two and the last two tuples are grouped. Are they grouped by date?

Comment: quote from OP question: "I already sorted the data". So you don't need to know that information.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already sorted your data, you can convert the lists to tuples and create a tuple (couple) of tuples 2 by 2:

```
l = [['A123', '2012-01-01', 'estrogen'],['A123', '2012-01-01', 'ibuprofen'],['A123', '2014-01-01', 'oxaliplatin'],
 ['A123', '2014-01-01', 'penicilin']]

result = [(tuple(l[i]),tuple(l[i+1])) for i in range(0,len(l),2)]
print(result)
```

variant using `zip` and sliced sub-lists:

```
result = [(tuple(u),tuple(v)) for u,v in zip(l[::2],l[1::2])]
```

you don't control the way the data is printed unless you use `pprint` module.

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(result,width = 50)
```

Since I chose a width of 50, I get one element per line (it depends on the data, but it seems that it provides exactly the output mentioned in your question, horizontal alignment included)

```
[(('A123', '2012-01-01', 'estrogen'),
  ('A123', '2012-01-01', 'ibuprofen')),
 (('A123', '2014-01-01', 'oxaliplatin'),
  ('A123', '2014-01-01', 'penicilin'))]
```

Comment: okay but do you want to group 2 by 2 or by code/date? Because if it's the latter, the other answer is the one.

Comment: The nested lists are already sorted by code and date:

list.sort(sampledata, key=itemgetter(0,1,2))

The output needed is for each pair to be returned as a comma- separated tuple, one per line.  If that makes sense.  Your code works and is adjustable if let's say it needed to be triplets or single.

Comment: I'm relieved. You didn't mentionned that you had a fixed number of items in each group. If it's not the case, my answer isn't valid (at least the first part, and you need `itertools.groupby`. I've got the finger on the button to delete it...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case for [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> data = [['A123', '2012-01-01', 'estrogen'],
...  ['A123', '2012-01-01', 'ibuprofen '],
...  ['A123', '2014-01-01', 'oxaliplatin'],
...  ['A123', '2014-01-01', 'penicilin']]
>>> [tuple(grp) for key, grp in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[:2])]
[(['A123', '2012-01-01', 'estrogen'], ['A123', '2012-01-01', 'ibuprofen ']),
 (['A123', '2014-01-01', 'oxaliplatin'], ['A123', '2014-01-01', 'penicilin'])]
```

This groups all items that have the same first two elements (`key=lambda x: x[:2]`) together in one tuple. Note that the data has to be sorted by the key for this to work, but according to you this is already the case.